# how to extend the get() method in eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to extend the method `get()` in eloquent class, to add some code that does a join whenever it is called.

Whenever a method `all()`, find or `get()` is called, add that join:

```php
static::join('clientes', 'clientes.id', '=', 'faturas.cliente_id');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)? You can also set `protected $with = array('clients');` in your Model.

You could also overload the `newQuery` Method by extending the Model class.

```php
class BaseModel extends Model {

    public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
    {
        $builder = parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted);

        $builder->join('clientes', 'clientes.id', '=', 'faturas.cliente_id');

        return $builder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! One more question ...

I created an attribute in my eloquent model like that

protected $ table = 'products';
protected $ view = 'v_products';

if the method called is a "select" like all (), find () or get () I want to use a view, but, if the method update () or insert () use the table.

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide some more info about your view? Can you perform SQL updates on your view? What does the view do?